# Create instance of custom many to many relationship typeorm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, many-to-many, typeorm

I have a many to many relationship beetwen prefecture and module. I built a custom relationship because i needed an extra column.
My question is: what is the best approach to create the instance of prefecture?

**Prefecture Entity**

```
@Entity()
export class Prefecture { 
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;
   
   //other attributes

    @OneToMany(() => ModulePrefecture, (modulePrefecture) => modulePrefecture.prefecture)
    modules: ModulePrefecture[]
```

**ModulePrefecture Entity**

```
@Entity()
export class ModulePrefecture {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string

    @ManyToOne(() => Prefecture, (prefecture) => prefecture.modulos)
    prefectura: Prefecture

    @ManyToOne(() => Module)
    module: Module

    @Column()
    @Min(1)
    @IsInt()
    amount: number
    
}
```

**My input is shomething like this**

```
{
  //other atributes
  modules: [{
            "id": "29ba1c6f-43ab-4e23-8a6c-27c39a57a069",
            "amount": 5
        },{
            "id": "29ba1c6f-43ab-4e23-8a6c-27c39a57f901",
            "amount": 10
        }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  code show that's you used many to one and one to many
for many to many tables i suggest to check typorm many to many explain
https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/many-to-many-relations